# Alternative for a Factory Design Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am learning about design patterns and I wanted to know what would be an approachable design for this problem.

I have the class FormObject with different properties one of them being the Id. The flow will be something like so:

FormObject ---> processEngine -----> OutputClass

Process is basically going to take the id of FormObject and get different properties from other lists, and the results of these list I would like to return it in the OutputClass like so:

```
public class OutputClass {

  List<FormObjectDetails1> list1;
  List<FormObjectDetails2> list2;
  List<FormObjectDetails3> list3;
  List<FormObjectDetails4> list4;

  //getters and setters. 

}
```

The processEngine is what I have not determine what it will be. I have read about the factory design patter but I don't think path since this pattern relates more to related objects.

Can someone point me on the right direction? 
Thanks.

Comment: OutputClass would be the created object ?, and ProcessEngine is the factory right ?, FormObject is just the data that ProcessEngine uses to create the object ?. Do you have more than 1 type of OutputClass ?

Comment: hey, @Francisco. The data would be different within the lists but basically the same OutputClass format

Comment: Every solution can't fit into one of existing design patterns. As long as your are fine with your solution, just proceed with it.